# Why won't my iPad 2 let me turn bluetooth on?

Tags: keyboard, ipad, bluetooth

This issue is about an interstate family member's iPad 2, so I'm afraid my knowledge of the issue and ability to troubleshoot are rather limited, but I'd appreciate any general help available.

The iPad is (or was) connected to an Apple bluetooth keyboard. It has been working up until today when, apparently, each time the bluetooth is turned on in the settings, it immediately reverts to being off. Is there a known or common reason for this to occur? Is there any solution?

I thought that it might be a power-saving thing, but apparently the iPad had near to full charge, and I can't think of much else.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using?

Comment: By "off" do you mean the actuall setting turns off in the settings app, or do you mean the bluetooth logo in the bar at the top dims to a light grey indicating it's not being used?  COuld it be as simple as the batteries in the keyboard being gone, and as such the bluetooth has nothing to connect to, effectively making it unused, or "off"?

Comment: Before trying anything more drastic, I would definitely power cycle the iPad completely - hold down standby button, swipe to power off, wait until it shuts down, then boot it up again. I've had a similar issue with Bluetooth 2 or 3 times with Macs and a reboot always fixed it. And iOS devices are really just restricted Macs on ARM CPUs…

Answer (score 1):

Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings.

No loss of data, you'll just have re-enter wifi passwords and re-pair Bluetooth devices.

If this fails then Restore.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could do:

1. Try restarting the iPad
2. Do a software restore of the iPad by pluggging the up to your PC or Mac and choosing the resore option

Hope this helps!

Comment: A software restore is pretty drastic for a Bluetooth problem... There are many more (less drastic) ways to try first before restoring your iPad!